# My PC does not shut down properly since I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: upgrade, shutdown

I have a desktop PC. I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04.  I click on the tool icon in the top right hand corner and click on Shut down.  The screen goes blank after a while, and an energy saver message appears. My PC is still running.  I end up having to press and hold the power button on the box to shut down.